# Invalid literal for int with base 10

Tags: python

I getting this error when running my code line 49, in total_energy last_digit+=int(dig) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:'

```
def total_energy(data):
    last_digit=0
    lines= data.split('\n')

for line in lines:
    if len(line)>6:
        your_digits=line[-15:].split(',')

    for dig in your_digits:
         last_digit+=int(dig)

print last_digit
```

I've also tried float but the same error.
http://pastebin.com/1UpzeAgD This is the data the code is working through.
Any help would be great!

Comment: you are trying to convert to int a non-int string. for example, if you try to do `int('a')`, you will get that error "Invalid literal for int with base 10". Check  your_digits's for and print them.

Comment: Hint: what happens when you try to convert the empty string to an integer with `int("")`?

Comment: You should use the `csv` module to parse files of *comma-separated values* ;)

Comment: Do `try: last_digit += int(dig)` // `except: print your_digits` and post what's printed

Comment: I found what adam said that it's getting an empty string and I think the error is with the  'your_digits=line[-15:].split(',')' part. I'm also unfamiliar with the csv module

Comment: InspectorGadget I get this: http://pastebin.com/Y9Qw4Kex It was quite large so I didn't want to put it in here

Comment: Are you looking to add the last 15 numbers?

Comment: No the last 9 numbers for eg. in the first data line 05:00,9.0,0.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,19,31 Adding the numbers after the (05:00,9.0,0.0) so 0+0+0+0+0+0+0+19+31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your origin data:

```
line89: 06:28,9.1,2.3,0,0,0,0,30,0,0,89,0
line90: 06:29,9.1,2.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,87,0
```

You encountered this error when you try to parse line 90 with `int('')`. As you can see, data in line 90 has a shorter length which makes `line[-15:]` in your code returns unexpected result.

You have to edit the way you get your_digits.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

f = open('data_printed.txt', 'r')
data = f.read()
f.close()

last_digit=0
lines= data.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    if len(line)>6:
        your_digits=line.split(',')[-7:]  # here to get last 7 elements you want
    for dig in your_digits:
        last_digit+=int(dig)

print last_digit
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: @user3491814 Could you please tell me what kind of error this time? The same?

Comment: Yer the same  line 51, in total_energy
    last_digit += int(dig)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: @user3491814 Can you give me content of line 51? It seems OK from my side.

Comment: WAIT NO! Sorry I was executing my old code :(( Your code works!

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

answer = 0
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter=','):
        nums = (int(i) for i in line[3:])
        answer += sum(nums)
print answer
```